# "Your system has run out of application memory." chrome using over 100 gb

Tags: google-chrome, memory

My computer was being very slow and then I got an error that my system is running out of application memory. But I was surprised to see chrome using 114 **GB** *not MB* of application memory.

[image]

Is this possible? That seems way too high. I had a lot of tabs open but not any more than usual. Could a website be causing this?

Answer (score 3):

Google Chrome has its own task manager built-in that can let you see what's happening. Poorly written JavaScript on a website as well as extensive advertising and tracking could consume an enormous amount of RAM.

Menu -> More Tools -> Task Manager

[image]